# What convex polygons admit 60 degree rotational symmetry?

Tags: geometry, rotations

I was trying a problem from a contest,i.e rmm that involved these kind of polygons and I tried to find all polygons that admit 60 degree rotational symmetry. I believe intuitive that it has to do with regular hexagons at least for the case when it has at most 6 edges but i cannot prove rigorous.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: To have a 60 degree rotational symmetry means that rotating by 60 degrees gives the same polygon. In particular, a vertex $A_1$ must rotate to another vertex $A_2$. Similarly $A_2$ rotates to $A_3$, which is thus a 120 degree rotation from $A_1$. This goes on to $A_4, A_5, A_6$ until finally $A_7$ will be a $360$ degree rotation from $A_1$. I.e., $A_7 = A_1$. So $A_1$ is part of a six-element loop of vertices. Every other vertex in the polygon has to be part of its own six-element loop. So the number of vertices in the polyon must be divisible by $6$.